# Setting gc.refLogExpire

Tags: git

How do I set gc.reflogExpire so that items will never expire?
What other time interval formats does it accept?

The man page says that you can set it to "90 days or 3 months," but doesn't specify what format it expects.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Setting gc.refLogExpire to "never" should do the trick.

```
git config gc.reflogExpire "never"
```

Answer (score 8):

I’m not sure where the format is documented, if at all, but `git reflog` uses the `approxidate` function from [`date.c`](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=blob;f=date.c) to parse the expiry time. One of the possible values is “never.”

Answer (score 1):

Setting in cli

- day: `git reflog expire --expire=180`
- never: `git reflog expire --expire=never`

Or

Setting this reflogExpire in you .gitconfig file

```
[gc]
    reflogExpire = never # Make reflog never expire
```