# For how long can you restore/recover a deleted branch on GitHub?

Tags: git, github

This is not a question on *how* to restore lost branches in Github, but rather how long you have to restore a deleted branch through the following user case story:

Within a pull request (often used as a place for code review) the branch can be merged and then deleted, all in the github GUI.  Should you choose to delete it, you are given the option with a bold and underlined word, to "restore" the branch.

I suspect this option has a time limit and that github doesn't keep this available indefinitely.

**Does github have a time limit on how long you can do this?  If it does, what is that time limit?**

Comment: It looks like all the answers cover the case where a pull request was created.

What happens if I _never_ create a pull request, and I delete the branch directly in github UI? (Assume I don't have  a local clone).

Comment: I highly suspect it is gone in that case. @MarcelloRomani. They probably have a git gc run regularly that would wipe that out as being unreachable.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I asked [GitHub Support](https://github.com/contact), this was their response (emphasis mine):

> We use a separate ref namespace for all Pull Requests which we use for various things including restoring the branch. Since we keep those [Pull Request] refs indefinitely, ***there's no time limit on restoring a branch***.

You can see these special references in your remote by using the following:

```
$ git ls-remote | grep pull
From git@github.com:<username>/<remote>.git
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa        refs/pull/1/head
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb        refs/pull/1/merge
cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc        refs/pull/2/head
dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd        refs/pull/2/merge
```

The references are namespaced under `refs/pull/<pull request number>/`. The `head` reference points at the tip of the branch that's being pull requested, i.e. the last commit on the branch. I'm not sure what the `merge` reference is though.

Comment: The `merge` branch seems to be the cache of a trial merge with master. `git fetch origin bbbbbbbb; git log --oneline --graph bbbbbbbb`

Answer (score 6):

GitHub support would have a definitive answer, but I suspect it is based on the default 90 days period before automatic purge of [the **`reflog`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17859891/6309).

```
gc.<pattern>.reflogexpire
```

> `git reflog` expire removes `reflog` entries older than this time; **defaults to 90 days**.
>   With "`<pattern>`" (e.g. "`refs/stash`") in the middle the setting applies only to the refs that match the `<pattern>`.

But... I you had a local copy with that branch still declared in it... nothing would prevent you to push said branch back to the gitHub repo ;)

[Cupcake](https://stackoverflow.com/users/456814/cupcake)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17954767/6309) (upvoted) give that support answer: **no limit**, which means those two [settings are both set to **`never`**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/199728/6309):

- `gc.reflogexpire`
- `gc.reflogexpireunreachable`

That makes sense for a hosting repo service which doesn't modify those repos locally, and only store modifications pushed from external contributors.

---

Update Git 2.22 (Q2 2019, five years later): that last case (setting `gc.reflogexpire` and `gc.reflogexpireunreachable` to `never`) is better handled.

See [commit bf3d70f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bf3d70fe93109616eb339e12dc9a7969b0bf025b), [commit 978f430](https://github.com/git/git/commit/978f4307638917127704716b754aed0953452bf4) (28 Mar 2019), [commit fe66776](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fe66776db0b841d4d4cf64f078e1ffd82193442a), [commit a65bf78](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a65bf78c4db0dda04ce726250ed84d23f109433f), [commit cd8eb3a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cd8eb3a094c51482c80a97589e4aff53af2c7c63), [commit e5cdbd5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e5cdbd5f7048d5dc9d84a7d1f2c467f0ebf4ac0b) (15 Mar 2019), and [commit 8bf1444](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8bf14444c3989aa0f5b01ba67dfb4b592e6c30d3) (13 Mar 2019) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit f3c19f8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f3c19f85c5aad6d3c8b56c3b2f3dfbf00852c8c4), 25 Apr 2019)</sup>

> ### `gc`: handle & check `gc.reflogExpire` config
>
> Don't redundantly run "`git reflog expire --all`" when `gc.reflogExpire` and `gc.reflogExpireUnreachable` are set to "`never`", and die immediately
>   if those configuration valuer are bad.
>
> As an earlier "assert lack of early exit" change to the tests for "`git reflog expire`" shows, an early check of `gc.reflogExpire{Unreachable,}`
>   isn't wanted in general for "`git reflog expire`", but it makes sense
>   for "`gc`" because:
>
> 1. Similarly to [8ab5aa4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8ab5aa4bd8e218b9658dbdd7f5bfcaa512f607dc) ("`parseopt`: handle malformed `--expire` arguments more nicely", 2018-04-21, Git v2.18.0-rc0) we'll now die early if the config variables are set to invalid values.
>      We run "`pack-refs`" before "`reflog expire`", which can take a while, only to then die on an invalid `gc.reflogExpire{Unreachable,}` configuration.
> 2. Not invoking the command at all means it won't show up in track output, which makes what's going on more obvious when the two are set to "`never`".
> 3. As a later change documents we lock the refs when looping over the refs to expire, even in cases where we end up doing nothing due to this config.

Answer (score 6):

Note that some pull-request pages on GitHub **will not show** the Delete/Restore branch buttons, even though the references are safely stored [as described by Cupcake](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17954767/456814).

This probably means the same branch was used again in a later pull request. Search the repo (in GitHub) for the **branch name** and check the latest pull request on that branch. You should find the UI to restore (or delete) the branch there.